# How can I manipulate the Packageversion on a multi target project when manipulation comes from a NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, build, nuget, multitargeting

I have a NuGet package with a targets file which manipulates the PackageVersion depending on the current context (When the branch is master it's creates a preview).

This is working well on a normal project but when I use this in a multi target project it's not working.

How can I correct this?

I have attached a sample project. https://1drv.ms/u/s!At1IZ7t_aXW-iNRchOhliGP8dunGHg?e=11dW4F
To reproduce the problem:

1. Unzip all files
2. You need a local NuGet Feed
3. Entry the name of your local NuGet Feed in BuildConfig/publish.bat
4. Call publish.bat in BuildConfig
5. Run "dotnet pack" in Consumer

This creates a package of consumer with version 1.0.0. This should bie 1.0.0-xdev.

When you change Consumer.csproj so that TargetFramework is used the correct version is created

I have tried the version modification outside of the target but this leads to problems when the version number is specified in a Directory.Build.Targets file

I have tried different BeforeTargets in but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When** you use **multi-targetframeworks** property like  `<TargetFrameworks>net461</TargetFrameworks>`, `build` folder of the nuget package cannot act well and it cannot service for multi-target frameworks, only for single taget framework.

**Instead**, you should abandon `build` and use `buildCrossTargeting`.

Under `BuildConfig` project, if it is a new sdk project, please use this

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="BuildConfig.targets" Pack="true" PackagePath="buildCrossTargeting" />"
</ItemGroup>
```

If you use **nuspec** file, you should use this undr the file:

```
<file src="BuildConfig.targets" target="buildCrossTargeting/" />
```

**You should note** that the `xxx.targets` files should be under `buildCrossTargeting` folder directly without any sub folders, otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution. I have to use both `build` and `buildCrossTargeting` because I have projects with multi targets and others with single targets but now its working.