# NuGet doesn't treat CopyToOutputDirectory correctly with linked file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, csproj

I have the following declared in my `csproj`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="TextFile1.txt" Link="Files\TextFile1.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Files\TextFile2.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Upon building the application I am getting the following bin/debug structure
[image]
[image]

As you can see both files are in the subdirectory `Files`, and no text file is in the root folder, since the file in the root folder isn't marked as `<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>` but the link is.

Now I want to pack this application, which fails to respect my linking of the file and dumps the `TextFile1.txt` into the root folder.

The created `*.nuspec` file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ConsoleApp44</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>ConsoleApp44</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net5.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/net5.0/TextFile1.txt" buildAction="Content" />
      <files include="any/net5.0/Files/TextFile2.txt" buildAction="Content" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the `TextFile1.txt` and `TextFile2.txt` from the nuget package to be copied into the same folder structure into the main project's output folder, you could try this:

Two tips:

1. to make files from `nupkg` be copied into the main project's output folder, you should use `<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>`.
2. use the `PackagePath` to specify the folder structure

Use this part under `ConsoleApp44.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="TextFile1.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Link>Files\TextFile1.txt</Link>
            <PackagePath>content\Files;contentFiles\any\any\Files</PackagePath>
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="TextFile2.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Link>Files\TextFile2.txt</Link>
            <PackagePath>content\Files;contentFiles\any\any\Files</PackagePath>
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

**Actually**, the `PackagePath` is to specify the custom output folder structure into the main project when you install the nuget package. You can change the structure according to your needs.

**Then**, you should re-pack the lib project, uninstall the old version of the nuget package, [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`. After that, reinstall the new release version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Only noticed after @Andy's answer, that the files didn't output when I used the nuget package, so I actually had two issues the files didn't output and the folder structure wasn't how I liked it. So, what I read from your answer both issues got tackled and I don't have to alter the *.nuspec file manually, will try it tomorrow and report back, but seems promosing. Do you know where I can find documentation of `PackageCopyToOutput` and the likes, isn't the first time I wanted to alter my nuget package and failed to do so, and fought the only way is to manually edit the nuspec file?

Comment: Since now, you could directly modify the csproj only for new-sdk project to pack nuget package without writing an additional nuspec file. My answer quite has a bit problem. Now you donot have to worry about it, I have updated my answer. Hope any feedback tomorrow!

Comment: [Check this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package).

Comment: This is awesome -- I never knew about `<PackageCopyToOutput>` That adds the `copyToOutput="true"` attribute that was in my answer automatically. That's been driving me nuts for years.

Comment: @Andy, Sorry for that. I intended to contact the owner. And be glad to know that it does help for you:)

Comment: @RandRandom, any update about it? Does it work during your test?

Comment: Sorry, that I failed to keep my promise.

Comment: Just checked and seems to work as expected.

Comment: I have one little question though, maybe you know what I am doing wrong. My `csproj` is declared as a multi-target project eg. `<TargetFrameworks>netframework4.7;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>` instead of `any\any` - why two any in the first place? - I tried to declare it like this `<PackagePath>content\Files;contentFiles\any\$(TargetFramework)\Files</PackagePath>`

Comment: (cont) ... but `$(TargetFramework)` seems to be empty and it resulted in a package with where the files are stored in this path `ConsoleApp44.1.0.0\contentFiles\any` it seems like it wants a subdirectory for the targetframewok or any, but I can't seem to specify the target framework. So the double `any\any` produce this, `ConsoleApp44.1.0.0\contentFiles\any\any\Files` would like to have two seperate folders for the targetframework eg. `ConsoleApp44.1.0.0\contentFiles\any\net5.0\Files`

Comment: Tough, it isn't necessary for my use case, it is just me being picky, everything seems to work fine with `any\any` in place.

Comment: Just see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#package-folder-structure). It is the feature of contentFiles node. And it should be the structure like `/contentFiles/{codeLanguage}/{TxM}/{any?}`. The first `any` is the file type: like `cs`,`vb`, `any` is generic, it means it could deal with all the types. The second `any` is the targetframework, `any` means that all the targetframework could install the below content files. So use `any\any` is the easiest way. Also, you cannot use `targetframework` under pack process with multiple targetframeworks.

Comment: I find it is an issue and you should report to [the team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8). It is always empty under that during the extra pack process. To avoid that, use `any\any`. Or you should specify them one by one. Use `any\net47` and `any\net5.0`. Most similar issue like [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915099/creating-a-nuget-package-with-exe-file-as-content-file/65933251#65933251). You should avoid using `targetframework` under multiple targetframeworks during pack process.